# Unable to view complete case number - How to remove salesforce console standard tabs Bold Header

Tags: apex, lightning, tab, console, style

In Console App, when I open Account and then open any case inside it, the active case tab is Bold and the case number is truncated.
I wonder it happened with recent release of salesforce couple of days ago.

Is there a way to turn off this settings or customize it? Since these are standard tabs.

PFB screenshot for ref:

**Active Case Tab**

[image]

Active other tab - case number is completely visible

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It's not currently possible to change the Tab titles in the Console without customisation. There is an open Idea available to vote on if you'd like to:

[Change tab titles in service console](https://ideas.salesforce.com/s/idea/a0B8W00000GdgXLUAZ/change-tab-titles-in-service-console)

Unfortunately I doubt this will address the truncation of the tab, as this is controlled automatically by Salesforce as part of the console.

Comment: Could you elaborate on customization ? Business is having hard time to identify cases especially if they are on call. They need to hover or focus on another tab to just see the number.